# Wordpress Image not showing in uploads folder after transfer domain name

Tags: wordpress

I transferred my site https://example.be to a development URL https://example.dev.be.
I take for example this image on example.be:

https://example.be/app/uploads/2023/11/suite.jpg: the image displays well in the media and it displays well on the site, but when I go to see the location in the uploads folder, the image does not exist, but the link https://example.be/app/uploads/2023/11/suite.jpg displays the image despite it not being present in the uploads folder at the indicated location.

Now let's take the same image on example.dev.be:

https://example.dev.be.be/app/uploads/2023/11/suite.jpg: the image is displayed in the media, but it is invisible as if it is not loading and it is not displayed not on the site either, and when I go to see the location in the uploads folder, the image does not exist, but the link https://example.dev.be/app/uploads/2023/11/suite .jpg does not display the image.

I tried to regenerate the permalinks, to export my database with BetterSearchReplace but nothing works

Comment: Did you copy the images to the uploads directory? If the links are right you and you copied the images then it might be an issue with your webserver configuration as I noticed you added /app/ to the URL.